# How to get min value from multiple columns for a row in SQL

Tags: sql, dashdb

I need to  get to first (min) date from a set of 4 (or more) columns.

I tried

select min (col1, col2, col3) from tbl

which is obviouslly wrong.

let's say I have these 4 columns

```
col1     |  col2     | col3  |  col4
1/1/17   | 2/2/17    |       | 3/3/17
```

... in this case what I want to get is the value in col1 (1/1/17). and Yes, these columns can include NULLs.

I am running this in dashDB

the columns are Date data type,

there is no ID nor Primary key column in this table,

and I need to do this for ALL rows in my query,

the columns are NOT in order. meaning that col1 does NOT have to be before col2 or it has to be null AND col2 does NOT have to be before col3 or it has to be NULL .. and so on

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: You need to get the min value for each row, or the min value from all rows?

Comment: And any id or primary key column in your table?

Comment: Using Scalar function you can try like this - SELECT ID, (SELECT MIN([date]) FROM (VALUES(Date1),(Date2),(Dateblah)) x([date])) MinDate
FROM TableName; Not sure whether this will work in dashdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DB support least function, it is the best approach

```
select 

least 
(
nvl(col1,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')),
nvl(col2,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')),
nvl(col3,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')),
nvl(col4,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
)
from tbl
```

Edit: If all col(s) are null, then you can hardcode the output as `null`. The below query should work. I couldn't test it but this should work.

```
select 
case when 
    least 
    (
    nvl(col1,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')),
    nvl(col2,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')),
    nvl(col3,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')),
    nvl(col4,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
    ) 
    = TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
then null 
else 
    least 
(
nvl(col1,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')),
nvl(col2,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')),
nvl(col3,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')),
nvl(col4,TO_DATE('2901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
) 
end 
as min_date
from tbl
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, this works almost perfectlly. the only thing is that when ALL the columns are NULL I get 01/01/2910 ... I'd rather just get a NULL value. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If a `id` column in your table. Then

**Query**

```
select t.id, min(t.col) as min_col_value from(
    select id, col1 as col from your_table
    union all
    select id, col2 as col from your_table
    union all
    select id, col3 as col from your_table
    union all
    select id, col4 as col from your_table
)t
group by t.id;
```

Comment: like the touch with the `union all`, good for performance. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *first* date, then use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(col1, col2, col3, col4)
from t;
```

This returns the first non-`NULL` value (which is one way that I interpret the question).  This will be the minimum date, if the dates are in order.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean " if the dates are in order" ? do you mean that col1 has to be before col2 or it has to be null AND col2 has to be before col3 or it has to be NULL ...and so on? if so then, no. the columns are not in order>

Comment: @MikePala . . . The question uses the phrases "first (min) date".   That led me to think the dates are in order.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Id, CaseWhen (Col1 <= Col2 OR Col2 is null) And (Col1 <= Col3 OR Col3 is null) Then Col1 When (Col2 <= Col1 OR Col1 is null) And (Col2 <= Col3 OR Col3 is null) Then Col2 Else Col3 End As Min From YourTable
```

This is for 3 Column, Same way you can write for 4 - or more column.

Comment: @Mikhail I have edited the answer including the null case.